# Find command with prune option is not working in particular directory in KSH

Tags: find

I want to list down .success files in dly folder and not within dly folder recursively as below.

```
find /CD/dly/ * prune -name "*.success"
```

Above command is listing file list properly. However when I switch to /AB/dly/ and run the same command

1. `cd CD AB`
2. `find /AB/dly/ * prune -name "*.success"`

It is showing below error.

> find: bad option -ltr

Is it problem with AB directory? or something else?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a file `-ltr` in the directory. Not sure why you have the glob `*` in the `find` command, unless you want that to expand to all files/directories in your current directory. Should probably just be `find /CD/dly/ -prune -name "*.success"`

Comment: As suspected, there is file with name -ltr... Thank you so much.  Moreover, without * I'm unable to get file list I'm searching for.  That is the reason I'm using *

Comment: So `find /CD/dly/ . -prune -name "*.success"` ? Not really sure what the point of the `cd` is here

Comment: I was to list .success files in a specific directory without checking in its child directories... In ksh.... Please provide me the command.  This might solve my problems

Comment: Assuming your `find` has `-maxdepth`, just use that. i.e. `find /some/directory -maxdepth 1 -name "*.success"`. Otherwise do something like `find /some/directory ! -path '/some/directory' -prune -name "*.success"`

Comment: -maxdepth is not available in my ksh.. Will try the other option and let you know... Thank you